# C# SOAP object to PHP

Tags: c#, php, soap

I am trying to use WDSL SOAP in PHP. The initial connection seems to work fine but I am struggling to 'convert' some C# to PHP, in particular headers.

```
AreaSearchRequest request = new AreaSearchRequest();
request.GUID = "1234";
request.Location = "UK";

// Create AreaSearchHeader, assign AreaSearchRequest
AreaSearchHeader header = new AreaSearchHeader();
header.Request = request;
header.Validate = false;

// SOAP connection
soap.Open();

// Call the AreaSearch method response object
AreaSearchResponse response = soap.AreaSearch(header);

//Close API connection
soap.Close();
```

And here is my rough translation into PHP.

```
$wsdl = "https://whatever/";
$options = array(
    'trace' => 1,
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$request = array(
    'GUID'  => '1234',
    'Location' => 'UK',
);

$client->__soapCall('AreaSearch', $request);
```

What is really throwing me off is the header stuff to make a valid request! Thanks (sorry, I  have no experience of C# whatsoever).

Comment: Have you tried [`SoapHeader`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php)?

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how I can get a response from just sending a header? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using nusoap https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/ to do the heavy lifting.  I dont use PHP myself but a have a load of c# soap services that people I work with use nusoap to consume and they haven't had any issues

Comment: I have tried but apparently its dated and unsupported. The problem is if I am passing the parameters through the header (which is what seems to be happening in C#). As that is the case what am I meant to pass to the SOAP call I want to make? Slightly confused.